# DirectShow.net c# - Capture image and capture video in the same project

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I am very new to the **DirectShow.net** library.

I want to create a project which should use the **DirectShow.net** library and capture an image as well as video. Is there any link for a sample application of the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this could be that you use a frame grabber in your capture graph... kind of like:

source->frame grabber->avi mux->file writer

You can then capture images in your call back function, while the rest of the graph would continue capturing video.